# UIPickerView subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, subviews

I want to get all the subviews of UIPickerview. I have tried :

```
UIPickerView *pc=[[UIPickerView alloc]init];
pc.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 130);
pc.delegate=self;
pc.dataSource=self;
[self.view addSubview:pc];
NSLog(@"%d",[pc.subviews count]);
for(id ww in pc.subviews)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[ww description]);
}
```

in ViewDidLoad. Then the count of the subviews is returned 0. Then I have written

```
NSLog(@"%d",[pc.subviews count]);
for(id ww in pc.subviews)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[ww description]);
}
```

part in all of the datasource and delegate methods of pickerview. The result has not changed. 
  Before the pickerview shown on screen I want to delete some of the subviews. How can I get all the subviews before it has shown on the screen ? 
   Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to do this (there might be an easier way to achieve your end goal)?

Comment: @Wain How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

What if you did your editing of the view in ViewWillAppear instead of ViewDidLoad? This will make it so that you can edit the subviews before the view actually is displayed...

Comment: I have written it in viewwillappear but I can not get the subviews.

Comment: you could also try viewWillLayoutSubviews.  This is likely a better option since it is called as the subviews are actually layed out.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a subclass of UIPickerView and do your code there.